# From one node, how can I get a linked node in the shader graph

Tags: python, node-editor

Im trying to go from node to node via the the output / input links of the shader graph node tree.

How do I receive the linked node from another nodes output?

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.node_tree != None:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if type(node) is ShaderNodeUVMap and node.name == "UV4":
                #I want something like this
                print(node.outputs[0].link.node.name)
```

Comment: As a side note, better use `is not None` than `!= None` [What is the difference between “is None” and “== None”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

[image]

code:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.node_tree != None:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            
            if node.name ==  "Principled BSDF":
                #I want something like this
                print("name is:", node.outputs[0].links[0].to_node.name)
```

result:
name is: Material Output